# Erro no AndroidStudio "Unexpected char 0xe3 at 45 in Referer value: [LINK]"

Tags: android-studio, link

Tenho um app que já esta em uso faz um tempo, mas recentemente ele deu problema em um dos links que usa uma palavra com acento. Porém, antes esse erro não aparecia. O que vcs acham que pode ser?